# How show results of split like as table in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

i need to have a query that simulates a query to a table starting from a split of a string:

String:
`A-1:B-2:C-3`

Im trying some like that, but i cant get the other value:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhNjp.png)

```
SELECT (SELECT y.column_value AS val
           FROM TABLE(apex_string.split(p_str => r.column_value,
                                        p_sep => '-')) y
          WHERE rownum = 1) AS vall,
        (SELECT y.column_value AS val
           FROM TABLE(apex_string.split(p_str => r.column_value,
                                        p_sep => '-')) y
          WHERE rownum = 2) AS valr
   FROM TABLE(apex_string.split(p_str => 'A-1:B-2:C-3', p_sep => ':')) r
```

I need have a result as a query like the image:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8PFL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly, with regular expressions; `P7_VALUE` has been entered manually and is set to submit when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. In real scenario, I presume that its value will be fetched from the database as result of multi-select Select list or Shuttle item.

Query:

```
select regexp_substr(column_value, '^\w+') col1,
       regexp_substr(column_value, '\w+$') col2
from table(apex_string.split(:P7_VALUE, ':'))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and then use `SUBSTR` to get the left- and right-parts:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN_VALUE, 1, 1) AS vall,
       SUBSTR(COLUMN_VALUE, 3) AS valr
FROM   TABLE(apex_string.split(p_str => 'A-1:B-2:C-3', p_sep => ':'))
```

If you can have variable length parts then use `INSTR` as well:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN_VALUE, 1, INSTR(COLUMN_VALUE, '-') - 1) AS vall,
       SUBSTR(COLUMN_VALUE, INSTR(COLUMN_VALUE, '-') + 1) AS valr
FROM   TABLE(apex_string.split(p_str => 'A-1:B-2:C-3', p_sep => ':'))
```